# Installing a .NET Framework control in the visual studio toolbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio, custom-controls, toolbox

We currently use this project for installing .NET controls in the Visual Studio toolbox: http://vstudiotoolbox.codeplex.com/. This approach requires to run VStudio in the background resulting in a very slow operation. We noticed that many other component manufacturer can install their control instantly.

What other approaches exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165358.aspx][1]

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a tutorial article on how to do this:

[Visual Studio Toolbox Control Integration](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration)

I found project on CodePlex quite obsolete and updated it to work with Visual Studio 2012.

Other approaches include:

- Toolbox Controls Installer (TCI) Package - probably the quickest and easiest way
- VSI and VSIX packages
- VSPackage - the most powerful, and most complicated way

I have discussed the updating and uninstallation in the article as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a VSI file and use [Tool.InstallComponents Command](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Apr/21/Installing-controls-to-the-Visual-Studio-Toolbox). Really simple actually. Also read [Toolbox Control Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166486.aspx) article at MSDN.

Sample VSI template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VSContent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vscontent/2005">
  <Content>
    <FileName>Web Connection\WebConnectionWebControls.dll</FileName>
    <DisplayName>Web Connection</DisplayName>
    <Description>Web Connection Toolbox controls for use with the Web Control Framework in VS.NET</Description>
    <ContentVersion>1.0</ContentVersion>
    <FileContentType>Toolbox Control</FileContentType>
  </Content>
</VSContent>
```

Then run the command: `devenv.exe /command Tools.InstallCommunityControls`

Comment: Will this approach work on all VS.NET editions? 2005, 2008 and 2010?

Comment: According to the documentation, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have discovered so far: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/bf9ec1a9-d9eb-48b3-a081-414587f27f55/